# how to change runtime errors into english

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I am seeing run-time errors in local language of windows which is annoying (pic below). I have changed regional settings to English from Windows settings, and also international language from Visual Studio environments settings also added globalization `uiCulture="en-US"` into `web.config` but still no success, is there something I am missing?

[image: non-english pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok found out the solution just added lines below into application_error in global.asax

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you encounter a localized messaged and are looking for the original error message: You can use the service on unlocalize.com to translate back:

> [http://www.unlocalize.com/SearchResults.aspx?search=Uygulamas%C4%B1nda+Sunucu+Hatas%C4%B1](http://www.unlocalize.com/SearchResults.aspx?search=Uygulamas%C4%B1nda%20Sunucu%20Hatas%C4%B1)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from IIS configuration, it was not installed in an English Windows and the Error Page is not in English due to this.

See you

Comment: i just use cassini to run this application.

Comment: maybe is the same problem using Cassini instead of IIS, in general the culture information of Windows is only used to set decimal separator millions separator, date order ... bla bla bla.

Comment: @Aayan the error language should still depend on the version of Windows that you have installed. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161486/change-language-of-error-messages-in-asp-net

Comment: then maybe it is the same non-answer for the Cassini case...? @David: Regardless of the language of windows, it will always be possible to have locale-neutral (i.e. English) default messages. But you'll have to configure the process/application correctly somewhere. As I don't know where off-hand, I'll leave it to someone else to come up with the **answer**

Comment: ok i just created simple test application and run it with cassini which did display error message only in english. So the problem is because of the application, need to find out where it's set to local language as default.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your browser is asking for a non English page by default? What happens if you  change the default accepted language in, say, IE? You could find the settings in Options->General->Languages.