# Visual Studio 2010 with IIS throwing Exceptions in spanish :{

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, iis-7.5

My system is W7, english; IIS 7.5, english, and VS2010 SP1, also english; why is VS throwing exceptions in spanish and how can I make it throw them in english?

Comment: I think you need to be a little bit more specific. I doubt it's vs throwing errors. Is it your app running in iis that throws errors in spanish and is that during debugging or when exactly do you get the spanish exceptions. Figuring out what account is running the proces when you get spanish messages is relevant in figuring out why it does so

Comment: well yes obviously it's my app that throws the errors, I think the spanish exceptions happen only when I run applications under the context of IIS rather than cassini or a console application, etc.

Comment: Something like this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771836(v=ws.10).aspx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Change language of error messages in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161486/change-language-of-error-messages-in-asp-net)

The solution was to add the following to `web.config`

```
<system.web>
   <globalization uiCulture="en-US" />
</system.web>
```