# How to change IIS and NET framework languages to English

Tags: .net, iis, non-english

My server has no Russian language at all. Windows UI culture is English.
Also I add to web.config

```
  <globalization uiCulture="en-US" />
```

But all exception I still see in Russian. Why? I found LPKSETUP utility and it show me the same screen.

[image]

How to guarantee change IIS language and NET framework language to English?

[image]

Comment: Do any of the answers to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161486/change-language-of-error-messages-in-asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161486/change-language-of-error-messages-in-asp-net) help?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, Thank you. But I show result of this screen in my question. In this applet I have English as default system languages and I have not Russian languages in this list at all.

Comment: Have you tried setting the language of your browser?

Comment: This machine was probably built using a Russian Windows image, so that when .NET Framework was enabled as a system component, the Russian language pack (something like https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-language-pack-offline-installer-for-windows-4bee217e-4096-6922-eba9-3e3c27342ff6) was enabled automatically. In that way, any change you made afterwards won't remove the language pack. But you should customize IIS/ASP.NET to show your own error pages, instead of the default ones (which has security risks). Then your own pages can be in pure English.

Comment: Since you have set all of the configuration with english, could you please have a try to create another IIS server and check if it is in Russian language ?