# Change error/problem messages language in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code set to the language "english" but my error/problem messages are still in german. How or where can I change the language. Also please state the file (if it's needed) because I'm new to developing.

[image: Navigation bar is in english, problem message is in german]

Comment: You need to uninstall relevant language packs from your computer (.net Framework SDK language pack or core equivalent).

Comment: Following Link may help you
[Remove Language you have installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161486/change-language-of-error-messages-in-asp-net?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change language of error messages in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161486/change-language-of-error-messages-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Link may help you Remove Language you have installed

[Change language of error messages in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161486/change-language-of-error-messages-in-asp-net?rq=1)

Comment: Please refrain from adding what is essentially a "link-only answer". You should instead summarise the steps given on the linked page. In this case, since the link is to another SO question may  be consider flagging the question as a duplicate, you already put a link in the comments.